# Integral over fraction of trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, mathematica

I would like to calculate the following integral

$$
I_1(A,B,C) = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\phi}{1 + A \cos\phi + B \sin\phi + C},
$$

and if possible also

$$
I_2(A,B,C,D,E) = \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \frac{D \cos\phi + E \sin\phi }{1 + A \cos\phi + B \sin\phi + C}.
$$

Mathematica gives the following analytic expression 
$$
\frac{-2\text{ArcTanh}\Big(\frac{B + (1- A+C)\tan(x/2)}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2-(1+C)^2}}\Big)}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2-(1+C)^2}},
$$
for the primitive function of $I_1$. However, when using it to evaluate the definite integral, it yields zero, whereas a numerical integration shows that it is not zero.

Comment: Note that $A\sin\phi+B\cos\phi$ may be rewritten as $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\sin(\phi+\theta)$ for some fixed phase $\theta$. Because your integral is over one whole revolution $\phi$, the $\theta$ is irrelevant and may be discarded. This removes one parameter from your $I_1$ (and two parameters from $I_2$) and makes the integrand a bit neater.

Comment: And, of course, the constant $1$ may be absorbed into $C$.

Comment: Yes you are completely correct, however I wrote it like this because A,B and C are such that the denominator never becomes zero.

Comment: The denominator *can* become zero if $A^2 + B^2 \geq (C + 1)^2$---are you assuming that $A^2 + B^2 < (C + 1)^2$?

Comment: The analytic expression has $\tan x/2$ in it, which has problem at $x=\pi$, right in the middle of your interval.  So you can't use it, as is, here.

Comment: I am assuming that $\sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + C^2}\leq 1$.

Comment: @Funzies You'll still run into trouble when equality holds, e.g., when $A = 1, B = C = 0$, the denominator vanishes at $\phi = \pi$ (and that case, I think the integral diverges).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making the simplifications observed in the comments, we can rewrite the first integral as some fixed real multiple of
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{d\phi}{1 + M \sin \phi},$$
where $M = \frac{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}}{C + 1}$. Henceforth assume $|M| < 1$, so that the denominator is always positive, avoiding singularities.

Integrating formally gives that
$$\int \frac{d\phi}{1 + M \sin \phi} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 - M^2}} \arctan \left(\frac{\tan \frac{\phi}{2} + M}{\sqrt{M^2 - 1}}\right),$$
but we can see that this expression is not defined at $\phi$ for which $\frac{\phi}{2}$ is a singularity of $\tan$, that is, where $\phi = (2 k + 1) \pi$, $k \in \Bbb Z$, so the antiderivative can only be used to evaluate definite integrals of the integrand on intervals not containing odd multiples of $\pi$. One *can* certainly write down an antiderivative of the integrand continuous on all of $[0, 2 \pi]$, but it's easier to use the symmetry of $\sin$ to write the definite integral as
$$\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \frac{d\phi}{1 + M \sin \phi} .$$ In particular, the interior of the domain of integration contains no singularities of $\tan \frac{\phi}{2}$, so we can conclude that the value of this integral is
$$\lim_{\phi \nearrow \pi} \left[\frac{2}{\sqrt{1 - M^2}} \arctan \left(\frac{\tan \frac{\phi}{2} + M}{\sqrt{M^2 - 1}}\right) \right] - \lim_{\phi \searrow -\pi} \left[\frac{2}{\sqrt{1 - M^2}} \arctan \left(\frac{\tan \frac{\phi}{2} + M}{\sqrt{M^2 - 1}}\right) \right] = \frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{1 - M^2}}.$$

As for the second integral, applying the same formal simplifications as before leaves us with (some real multiple of) the integral
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{D \cos \phi + E \sin \phi}{1 + M \sin \phi} d\phi .$$
We can split the integral as 
$$D \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\cos \phi \,d\phi}{1 + M \sin \phi} d\phi + E \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin \phi \,d\phi}{1 + M \sin \phi} d\phi ,$$
and the obvious substitution leads to the vanishing of the first integral. We can then proceed similarly as before and express our remaining integral as a sum of two limits, yielding (if I managed this correctly)
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin \phi \,d\phi}{1 + M \sin \phi} = \frac{2 \pi}{M} \left(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - M^2}} \right) .$$

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer! However, somewhere there seems to be a small mistake. According to your results we should have $I_1 = \frac{2\pi}{(1-M^2)(1+C)}$. As a check, I computed the integral numerically and your result for, e.g. $A = 1/6$, $B=1/7$ and $C=1/9$. Your result gives $5.80611$, whereas the numerical result is $5.69451$. I checked and it does not seem that there are any numerical errors. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I already found the mistake: you made a typo in the limits expression: the result should be $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-M^2}}$.

Comment: You're right, thanks! I've now put in the missing radical.